# I'm looking to learn xtags for use with indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've been searching (on mobile) for a good user guide / tutorial on using XTags, I've got the manuals provided by Em Software but I was hoping for something more up-to-date and with visuals as well.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(I'm absolutely new to indesign / xtags )

Comment: I'm voting to close because you're asking about tutorials for an external plugin, check [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more info on scope for this website.